# Jquery is not working, even if used cdn?

Tags: jquery

I wrote the correct jquery code but it isnt working. please help!
PLease visit the link
for html doc: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RckO-f3czHvvWTbLiKcKw9LfV3YgJK6W/view?usp=sharing
 for jquery code : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rhthb2ryzH7y4Cqv-3fCOORnVA5QaGLw/view?usp=sharing
 for css code : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kvP_L48-ajNRcHxRp9VEx-voqv3vQa1e/view?usp=sharing
i even used a cdn for jquery and saved jquery file but it didnt work. please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading the jquery library first before your custom code that relies on jquery.

for example:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
 integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="loginscript.js"></script>
```

Also, you have errors on your provided code...(for example)

```
<img src="logo.jpg id="logo"> // missing quotes
```

And finally,  you have script written right after the start body tag... try moving it to the bottom before the closing body tag or include them all in your loginscript (see changes below as example, notice the changes on the jquery usage).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#signupbtn").click(function(){
$("#signupdiv").slideDown(1000);
$("#logindiv").hide();
});


$("#virtualkeyboard").hide();
$("#signupdiv").hide();


$("#virtualkey").click(function(){
$("#virtualkeyboard").slideDown(1000);
$("#prediv").height(300);
});
$("#closebtn1").click(function(){
$("#virtualkeyboard").hide();
$("#prediv").height(600);
});
}

);


function checkcookie(){
var username=getCookie("username");
if (username != ""){
    alert('Welcome again'+username);
    window.location="accounts.html";
}
else{
    window.location="login.html";
}
}

$("#signupbtn").click(function(){
    $("#signupdiv").slideDown(1000);
    $("#logindiv").hide();
});
$(function() {
    $("#virtualkeyboard").hide();
    $("#signupdiv").hide();
    $("username").hide();
});
$("#virtualkey").click(function(){
    $("#virtualkeyboard").slideDown(1000);
    $("#prediv").height(300);
  });
    $("#closebtn1").click(function(){
    $("#virtualkeyboard").hide();
    $("#prediv").height(600);
});


function logincheck(){
var user = document.getElementById('username');
var pass=document.getElementById('password');
if (user.value ==ayush && pass.value==anand){
    document.cookie="username=ayush; expires= mon 19 feb 2018; path=/";
}
else{
    window.location="login.html";
    incorrectusername();
}
}
```

for your html, something like this (notice the fixes on the html tags arrangement)

```
    <!doctype HTML>
    <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="loginstyle.css">
    <!--
    #0095d9;
    #d3d3d3 #0a242b #3f3f3f
    -->

    <title>Ayush Web: Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="welcomediv">
    <div id="prediv">
    <img src="welcomeimg.jpg" id ="welcomeimg">
    </div>
    <div id="virtualkeyboard">
    virtual keyboard here
    </div>
    <div id ="forgotpassword">
    forgot password form here
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="maindiv">
    <div id="logindiv">
    <br><br><br><br><br>
    <img src="logo.jpg" id="logo">
    <br><br>
    <h id="lohintitle"> Login </h>
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="your username">
    <br><br>
    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="your password">
    <br><br>
    <a href="#"> Forgot password?</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button id="loginbtn" onclick="logincheck()">Sign In</button>
    <hr class="hr">
    <button id="virtualkey">Use Virtual Keyboard</button>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button id="signupbtn">Join Now</button>
    </div>
    <div id="signupdiv">
    <br><br><br><br><br>
    <img src="logo.jpg" id="logo">
    <br><br>
    <h id="logintitle"> Sign Up</h>
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder=" your first name" required>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder=" your last name">
    <br><br>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder=" your email">
    <br><br>
    <input type="password"  id ="newpassword" name="password" placeholder=" your password" required>
    <br><br>
    <input type="password"  id ="confirmpassword" name="password" placeholder=" confirm your password" required>
    <br><br>
    <button onclick="signupfrmdata()" id="signupfrmbtn">Finish</button>
    <hr class="hr">
    <label>Have an account?</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button id="loginbtn"> Sign In</button>

    </div>
    </div>



    <script
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="loginscript.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your html file start  just after this '`<title> Ayush Web: Login </ title>`' code and before `<div id = "welcomediv">` like this:

```
 <title> Ayush Web: Login </ title> </head> <body> <div id = "welcomediv"> ....</body>
```

Your head is not close in a good place. After these corrections adds the following lines on head tag

```
<script
  src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity = "sha256-FgpCb / KJQlLNfOu91ta32o / NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8 ="
  crossorigin = "anonymous"> </ script>
```